# Oracle SQL query to count "children" in current query set

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, children

I have got an SQL query in Oracle with a multilevel subquery for generating my website navigation in the database. This query has a multilevel subquery because for each user I have to check whether they have the right to access this part of the navigation. The result looks kind of like the following:

```
ID | ID_PARENT | NAME    | LINK
------------------------------------------
 1               Main      ~/
 2            1  Sub1      ~/Sub1
 3            1  Sub2      ~/Sub2
 4            2  Sub1.1    ~/Sub1.1
 5            2  Sub1.2    ~/Sub1.2
 6            2  Sub1.3    ~/Sub1.3
```

The ID_PARENT column refers to the ID column of another row in the same table.

Now what I need is a query that, for each row, gives me the amount of rows **in the current query set** (because there exist other navigation entries that some users do not have the rights to, and I want to avoid making the same subquery twice) that have the current ID as ID_PARENT, so basically counts the children. With the example above the result I need should look like the following:

```
ID | ID_PARENT | NAME    | LINK     | CHILDREN
---------------------------------------------------------
 1               Main      ~/                2
 2            1  Sub1      ~/Sub1            3
 3            1  Sub2      ~/Sub2            0
 4            2  Sub1.1    ~/Sub1.1          0
 5            2  Sub1.2    ~/Sub1.2          0
 6            2  Sub1.3    ~/Sub1.3          0
```

I have tried a fair share of SQL queries, but none of them get me the result I need. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
with q(ID, ID_PARENT, NAME, LINK) as (
-- original query
) 
select ID, ID_PARENT, NAME, LINK
  ,(select count(*) from q q2 where q2.ID_PARENT = q.ID) CHILDREN
from q
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: I have a different problem, but I feel like this is very close to the answer I need. What allows you to refer to 2 different rows from the same table here? Is there something understood to go before "with"? Is the 2nd half dependent on what the "original query" is? Specifically, I'm trying to normalize a table that, instead of referring to the ID of another row, duplicates the other row's name.

Comment: @donutguy640 You'd better ask a separate question with more details. You'll also get a broader SO users attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can count() separately the record for your ID_PARENT and then join it with your main query.  Something like this:

```
 SELECT A.*, COALESCE(B.RC ,0) AS CHILDREN_NUMBER
 FROM YOURTABLE A
 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID_PARENT,COUNT(*) AS RC FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY ID_PARENT) B ON A.ID  = B.ID_PARENT;
```

Ouput:

```
ID  ID_PARENT   NAME    LINK    CHILDREN_NUMBER
1   NULL        Main    /       2
2   1           SUB1    /Sub1   3
3   1           SUB2    /Sub2   0
4   2           SUB1.1  /Sub1.1 0
5   2           SUB1.2  /Sub1.2 0
6   2           SUB1.3  /Sub1.3 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not really what I was looking for. The problem is that the table "YOURTABLE" in your suggestion is not a table but a query with multilevel subqueries. For your solution I would have to execute that query twice, and that is the thing I am hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this is same as above answer by etsa.

```
     select 
     n.id,n.parent_id,n.name,n.link,coalesce(b.children,0) 
     from navigation n 
     left join (select 
                    parent_id as parent,count(id) as children 
                    from navigation group by parent_id) b 
     on n.id=b.parent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution has the same "problem" as the etsa's.